# Parsing and Modifying local HTML with Node.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, github-pages

I kind of have a weird question that's probably very basic. I'm pretty new to web development and front-end stuff in general.

**Premise**
First of all, my only real other experience with JS is using node.js to make a discord bot, as well as use D3 to make some basic GUI stuff.
I'm trying to make a GitHub pages wiki for a game I play. In the game, there are units, which I've encoded as JSON files, as well as a folder of images. All I really want is a basic index.html page with links to HTML pages for all the units. But since units are constantly being added, I am constantly updating the JSON so I want to be able to generate the HTML files for the units as well as updating index.html automatically.

**The Method**
Since all I really know is node.js, I've been trying to use that to make the HTML files. What I'm trying to do right now is this hacky thing of using fs to read in the HTML files, then use jsdom to parse them into something I can use jquery to edit. After that I just want to serialize the jsdom into a string and use fs to write to the file. Right now I can successfully deserialize with jsdom and serialize the html back with fs. But I'm having trouble editing the actual HTML.

**Question**
First of all, I have no idea whether this is a good way to do what I've described at all, I'm still in the very early stages, so I'm welcome to suggestions on other libraries or just completely redoing the project. The closest thing I've found that's similar to what I want to do is this GitHub snippet from 10 years ago, unfortunately, I'm sure a lot of it is outdated and my puny knowledge is not able to adapt to this to modern js: https://gist.github.com/clarkdave/959811. I was wondering whether someone could do that for me, or suggest a better way of doing what I'm trying to do. You can see what I'm currently trying to do here: https://github.com/aayu3/ATBotJSONDependencies

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"In order to be able to generate HTML, and Auto-Update webpages based on a configuration, input, &/or data, you need a template engine. You might not know it, but that is what your building already, well sorta. You have the right idea, using **`fs`** to read your ***HTML***, but your going to need to go a few steps further."*

---

1. **Read your HTML files, and store the read HTML as a string inside your Node.js code-base.**

   - *"sounds like you have done this already."*

2. **Build a Parsing-Engine**

   - *"You can build one, or implement a pre-built parser via a Node.js module, you can probably find a few different parsers on **NPM**."*

3. **Create a Library that Manipulates Strings**

   - *"You need to implement a library that can alter the HTML after it has been read. You can implement a simple library, custom for a single webpage, or you can build something that is a bit more dynamic in its use, something that you can re implement for a later purpose, which, semantically, would actually be closer to an API, rather than a library."*
4. **Build/Implement a Compiler**

   - *"The last thing you need to implement is a **"compiler"**. This takes the HTML, that you have altered — which should be in the form of a string at this point — and compiles it back to HTML. Like the parser, you can implement a pre-built compiler, or write it yourself."*

---

> *"Most people do not build their own engines, because its not financially feasible. To build something quickly, and easily, its far more efficient to use a tool that has been pre-built, and a lot of the tools that already have template engines built into them, have been built by very good opensource developers, or companies with a lot of money (e.g. React is built by Facebook)."*

There's really no shortage to the options you have.

---

#### I have listed some alternate options you can choose below:

> *"Including a tutorial about building your own template engine, which is considered by most to be the hard way. The hard-way isn't always the worst way though. In this case, choosing the hard-way — building your own template engine — offers an insight to the mechanics of the popular tools that contemporary web developers use,"*

---

1. The first is the obvious **HTML Template Engine**.
   Right now [Handlebars](https://handlebarsjs.com/) and Pug are really popular. A template engine is essentially a rendering tool that that coverts a special variable syntax used in your html to data that is stored, usually, in JSON format somewhere, and if that data is dynamic, the variable in your page will change depending on the state of your data. It might sound a bit confusing at first, but I promise this is quite simple. Bellow is the syntax commonly used.

```
// Your Data.

{
  animal: "My little dog, Sophie.",
  place: "Santa Rosa, Ca.",
}
```

---

```
// Your HTML template, or your input.
<h3>{{place}}</h3>
<p>{{animal}}</p>
```

---

```
// Your HTML output, that is compile and rendered by your template engine.

<h3>Santa Rosa, Ca.</h3>
<p>My little dog, Sophie.</p>
```

- [Here is a link to an online tool](https://handlebarsjs.com/examples/simple-expressions.html) built by Handlebars, for experimenting with their template engine. In-fact I used that tool to create the example above.

---

**You have two other options**

2. For the second option, you could use a full blown framework like **React or Vue**. Personally I have never used React, but I have spent sometime with Vue. Vue implements the same **Double Curly Bracket Syntax** that the template engines use (which is demonstrated in the above example). Vue takes things a step further though, or it might be more correct to say Vue takes things 5-thousand and 42 steps further which is why some people choose it over a template engine, on the flip side it is also why many people choose to not use it (same goes for React). I am a Vanilla JS Guy myself...
3. ...and as a Vanilla lover the 3rd Option you have, is what I do. Build a simple yet extremely powerful template engine for yourself. Though this may sound the most ludicrous and time consuming, its not. The frameworks will take you far more time to learn, and building a template engine for your self only takes a few functions, though it would be quicker to implement one that's already made for you from Option #1 above, however; Building your own template engine ensures you understand whats going on under that hood of yours, and not only that, but you become a mechanic to your own engine under your hood. You will be able to swap parts and make adjustments as you please. Bellow is a small bit of code that looks simple, but has a lot going on in it.

```
var render = (template, data) => {
    return template.replace(/{{(.*?)}}/g, (match) => {
        return data[match.split(/{{|}}/).filter(Boolean)[0]]
    })
}
```

The snippet above was written by ShadowTime2000 at Hackernoon.com.

The snippet above is a great example for demonstrating the render function that is at the heart of most every JavaScript template engine (for the sake of correctness there are exceptions, but that is irrelevant here). The snippet above came from an entire guide that is a wonderful free resource that I suggest reading. Link is below.

[Shadowtime2000's Tutorial on Template Engines](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-create-new-template-engine-using-javascript-8f26313p)

By the way I don't know shadow-time, and I am not trying to market his stuff. I really like the way he thinks. IMHO, Shadowtime2000 writes, very useful tutorials/guides, which is becoming increasingly harder to find the more I learn.

I hope something above helps you mate,
CHEERS!